# Property 'Group' does not exist on type 'ForwardRefExoticComponent<InputProps & RefAttributes<HTMLInputElement>>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd, react-hook-form

I am trying to bind a react hook form on radio and radio group. However, I get following issue

```
Property 'Group' does not exist on type 'ForwardRefExoticComponent<InputProps & RefAttributes<HTMLInputElement>>'.  TS2339
```

This is the code

```
import { Radio as $Radio } from 'antd';
import { RadioProps, RadioChangeEvent } from 'antd/lib/radio';

import { Controller } from 'react-hook-form';
import { InputProps } from './types';

const Radio = React.forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, InputProps>((props: InputProps, ref) => {
  const { id, name, label, control } = props;
  return (
    <>
      <Controller
        name={name}
        control={control}
        render={(controlProps: RadioProps) => {
          const { onChange } = controlProps;
          return (
            <$Radio
              {...controlProps}
              id={id}
              checked={controlProps.value}
              value={controlProps.value}
              className="radio"
            >
              {label}
            </$Radio>
          );
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
});

export default Radio;

Radio.Group = (props: InputProps) => {
  const { id, name, label, control } = props;
  return (
    <>
      <Controller
        name={name}
        control={control}
        render={(controlProps: RadioProps) => {
          const { onChange } = controlProps;
          return (
            <$Radio.Group
              {...controlProps}
              id={id}
              checked={controlProps.value}
              value={controlProps.value}
              className="radio"
            >
              {label}
            </$Radio.Group>
          );
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

I could not figure out why I am getting such issue. How can I bind react-hook-form on Radio Group ?

Answer (score 3):

The type for you `Radio` variable is a react component, specifically `ForwardRefExoticComponent<InputProps & RefAttributes<HTMLInputElement>>`.  What you are doing is adding another component as a property on this component.  Typescript complains about that because a react component doesn't have any definition for a property called `Group`.

It is possible to add arbitrary properties to our component, but we have to tell typescript about them.

Here are the typings from the `antd` package:

```
interface CompoundedComponent extends React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<RadioProps & React.RefAttributes<HTMLElement>> {
    Group: typeof Group;
    Button: typeof Button;
}
declare const Radio: CompoundedComponent;
export { Button, Group };
export default Radio;
```

You can see that `Radio` is declared as both a react component and an object with properties `Group` and `Button`.

Instead of writing `Radio.Group = ...` I would create the `Group` as it's own component: `const Group = ...`.  Then combine the two together at the end before exporting.

```
type CompoundedType = typeof Radio & {
  Group: typeof Group;
}

const Compounded = Radio as CompoundedType;
Compounded.Group = Group;

export default Compounded;
```

The critical part here is `Radio as CompoundedType` which tells typescript to treat the type for `Compounded` as `CompoundedType` even though there is no `Group` property yet.  We need the `as` to override typescript's instincts.