# How to declare React.Component type for sub-components?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, react-typescript

I use external library with React components (e.g. "ui"):

```
import { Input } from 'ui'

export const LoginForm = () => (
    <Input name="login" value={login} />
    <Input.Password name="password" value={password} />
)
```

I have some types declarations (`types/ui.d.ts`):

```
declare namespace Ui {
    export interface InputProps {
        value?: string;

    }
    export class Input extends React.Component<InputProps> {
        static Password: any;
    }
}

declare module 'ui' {
    export import Input = Ui.Input;
}
```

How to declare type for `Input.Password`?

What I tried:

```
export class InputPassword extends React.Component<InputPasswordProps> {
   // ... 
}
```

```
declare namespace Ui {
    export interface InputProps {
        value?: string;

    }
    export class Input extends React.Component<InputProps> {
        static Password: InputPassword;
    }
}
```

But I am getting error:

```
JSX element type 'Input.Password' does not have any construct or call signatures.ts(2604)
```

Comment: I answered question a few days ago which is basically the same: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65783246/10431574  It takes some `as` casting to have a component as a property on another component but it's doable.

Comment: I'm not confident enough to post this as an answer but let me know if this works: https://tsplay.dev/OwEZ3N

Comment: @LindaPaiste it doesn't works for me. What is the difference with my code?

Comment: The difference is that you are trying to override/merge the declarations with an external library rather than declaring a type for your own component.  What’s the actual package?

Comment: I use ui-library from private corp npm repository (not from npmjs.com).
This ui-library contains component `Input` and sub-component `Input.Password`.

Comment: Is this better?  https://tsplay.dev/w181YW  If I understand correctly you are the user of the package, not the author, correct?  Are you getting errors when trying to declare the module, or when trying to use the components?

Comment: Yes, I am user of ui-library.
There are no actual difference between your tsplay links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me:

```js
declare namespace SbolLibUi {
    interface InputPasswordProps extends InputPropsBase {
        // specific properties
    }
    interface InputProps extends InputPropsBase {
        // specific properties
    }

    declare class Input extends React.Component<InputProps> {
        static readonly Password = class extends React.Component<InputPasswordProps> {
            // specific properties
        };
    }

    declare module 'ui' {
        export import Input = Ui.Input;
    }
}
```